# MySQL values get added to absurd decimal places randomly

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm using the node.js mysql module, and I have a line that does this:

```
await connection.query("UPDATE users SET balance=balance+? WHERE userid=?", [amount.toFixed(2), user.id])
```

The balance row is updated without problem, and balance goes up to 2 decimal places. However, sometimes randomly the row inside the MySQL table will get set with weird decimals.

WHAT HAPPENS:

amount is 10.5 and the user's balance is 25. The balances are updated, but sometimes it goes and makes the value inside of the MySQL to go to 30.500000000004 or numbers with really absurd decimal places, even though I never put them in.

Comment: never use double or float types for currency.  use int types (and count in pennies or the equivalent in your currency) or use decimal types, e.g. `decimal(10,2)`

Comment: I'm using VARCHAR for it. However if I do set that and for some reason my code still attempts to add a weird decimal will it crash and stop? Because right now whenever an error from the mysql it shuts down

Comment: *I'm using VARCHAR for it.* If so then DOUBLE intermediate datatype is used, with unpleasant effect which you see. If you want to continue this (incorrect) datatype usage then add ROUND or CAST to your query. *However if I do set that and for some reason my code still attempts to add a weird decimal will it crash and stop?* Be more specific, show an example(s) of "weird decimal".

Comment: By weird decimal, I mean decmials that are really small like 0.00000000005